# Problem updating ClamAv Definitions

Tags: clamav

My auto update of Clam Defs doesn't seem to be working and when I do

```
sudo freshclam
```

I get

```
ERROR: /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log is locked by another process
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log).
```

I've tried reinstalling Clam.. Same problem.

How can I solve it?

I tried the command from the linked question

```
$ sudo lsof /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log

lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND     PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
freshclam 21238 clamav    3wW  REG  253,1     3587 29757231 /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log
```

This seems wrong? Should I be worried? And how should I proceed?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the output. You can ignore the permission error. As the linked post explains, ClamAV runs as a daemon in the background. You do not have to run it yourself. In your question you say "My auto update of Clam Defs doesn't seem to be working" - if you have some reason to think that, other than the fact that you get this error when running `sudo freshclam`, which is normal, please [edit] your question to explain why you think the auto update is not working

Comment: The main reason i was concerned is the ClamTK Gui i installed through the built in Ubuntu Software program was reporting old virus Signatures and would not update despite all GUI and repeated terminal attempts. However after following the previously suggested steps all seems to be working correctly, now on Sig 23857. So if this correct all is well.  If not let me know. Thanks for the advice and please forgive me, im a novice :)

Comment: Sounds good! Nothing to forgive :) Clam's behaviour is confusing!